# Have you seen this topology before? (related to Furstenberg's arithmetic sequences)

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, integers

According to this [topology article](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/the-infinitude-of-prime-numbers-a-topological-proof/), we could replace $b$ in $a + b\Bbb{Z}$ with $b^{k}$ for any fixed $k \gt 0$ and we should still have a topology.

For instance unions of subsets of the form $a + b^k \Bbb{Z}$.  I verified the $\cap$ property for bases.

Have you seen this used before?

Let $\tau$ be the topology.  $\Bbb{Z} \in \tau: \Bbb{Z} = \cup_{a \in \Bbb{Z}}\{a + 0^k\}$.  $\varnothing$ is just the empty union, so is also in $\tau$.  Now with notation from the article, if $x \in B_{a,b} \cap B_{c,d}$, then $B_{a,b} = B_{x,b}, \ B_{c,d} = B_{x,d}$.  Notice that $x \in B_{x, bd}$, which is contained in the intersection.

I believe this set also forms a basis for a topology on $\Bbb{Z}$:
For fixed $k \gt 0$:
$$\{a + k^b \Bbb{Z}\} \\
$$

I wonder what can be done using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the sets $a + b\mathbb{Z}$, with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the [*profinite topology*](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Profinite_topology) on $\mathbb{Z}$.
For a prime $p$, the topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the sets $a + p^k\mathbb{Z}$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is the *pro-$p$ topology*. See [1, p. 75](https://books.google.fr/books?id=u8GWrhdhA2QC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=profinite+topology+on+a+group&source=bl&ots=w7qmtbgjKU&sig=4XXg25zodfaR1jOLh5fzV87l7R0&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=ibQSVZW6GYuu7gb0s4HIBA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=profinite%20topology%20on%20a%20group&f=false) for more details.

[1] L. Ribes, P. Zalesskii, *Profinite Groups*, A Series of Modern Surveys in Mathematics 40. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2010. xvi+464 pp. ISBN: 978-3-642-01641-7